# Rabbitmq: Publisher confirms in Nodejs amqplib

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am using [amqplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) as nodejs rmq client. I am using confirmChannel to publish a message with mandatory flag set.

Rabbitmq/Amqplib is not giving [return](https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_events) on channel, when a message is posted to a topic exchange with two queues, in which one of node which has a queue got terminated.

According to the [Documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#when-publishes-are-confirmed),

`For unroutable messages, the broker will issue a confirm once the exchange verifies a message won't route to any queue (returns an empty list of queues). If the message is also published as mandatory, the basic.return is sent to the client before basic.ack. The same is true for negative acknowledgements (basic.nack).`

When there are no queues to route, `return` is fired. And when both queues are present `ack` is received.

But during publishing if one of node got terminated which has a queue in it, I expected `return` event. Only `ack` is received in callback.

I am not sure whether it is Rabbitmq or amqplib behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is confusion here on what the expected behavior is.

**Mandatory** means that a message must be routable to a queue.  If there is at least one queue bound to the routing key, then the condition of mandatory is met. If not, the message is returned.

There are two ways to receive a return. First, you may use the [immediate](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.publish.immediate) flag. This tells the broker that the message must be immediately deliverable to a consumer (not just a queue).  Or, you can use the mandatory flag, as you are doing.

In either case, **if the message is deliverable, you should not expect it to be returned**. So, if one of your queues is down, but the other is up, you have satisfied the conditions of either flag and will not have a returned message.

**Publisher confirms** is different. This feature will tell the client when a message was accepted by the broker. If the broker successfully **accepts** the message, a confirm will be received regardless of where the message goes.

Based on commentary below, the following documentation is relevant.

> For routable messages, the basic.ack is sent when a message has been accepted by all the queues. For persistent messages routed to durable queues, this means persisting to disk. For mirrored queues, this means that all mirrors have accepted the message.

Comment: thanks for explanation. I have a question here. How is **acceptance** related to message getting delivered to all the queues as it is intended? I want broker to confirm **only** when the message is enqueued to **all** the queues that satisfy the routing key.

Comment: RabbitMQ only cares about intent to publish with regard to publisher confirms. Failure to route to any queue would be dealt with under the return method. In that case, you’d still get a positive confirm. There is no way to know where a message ultimately went, which is by design.

Comment: Then as a publisher, how know whether my message reached to all the queues or not ??

Comment: You’ll need to set up some sort of RPC mechanism. At that point, it’s an application concern, not a messaging concern.

Comment: In case of mirror queues, If a mirror goes down, still we get positive confirm as the above case?

Comment: See the documentation snippet that I posted above. Note it is directly below the documentation snippet in your original question.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. I just wanted to know the behavior. 
Definition of un-routable message still holds. When the mirror node got terminated, there still is no "return" to publisher because there is one mirror queue to send the data to. 
Now I am wondering, without RPC which adds extra timer logic at publisher, how exactly I should use RMQ messaging.

Comment: A queue going away is a different problem than what RabbitMQ is designed to address. Can you clarify the behavior of the system you’re trying to compensate for with whatever it is we are discussing here?

Comment: I am planning to use RMQ for Inter microservice communication. In my case the data NOT reaching to microservice1 and reaching microservice2 has severe outcomes/difficulties. I want to make sure that the sender microservice knows about this so that it can retry later point.

Comment: So I am trying to use mirrored queues to see whether it solves the confirmation issue.

Comment: Can you provide a sequence diagram or some other explanation of your orchestration with more detail?

Comment: I will provide soon. Thanks for the help. I will have to read more on rabbitmq before that.

Comment: I have no doubt that there is a way to leverage RMQ to get what you need - but yes, let's try to understand more about the design of this particular interaction before going down that route. Maybe ask a new question?

Comment: Give me sometime. I will comeback.